# FFmpeg pan filter and clipping

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a file that has one video stream and one audio stream with 8 channels. I want to create a new file that will only contain the first 2 channels of the audio stream (no video). I can do this using the [pan filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan). I also want to clip the file. I can do this using the [-ss and -t options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options). However, when I try to do both together, I get an error.

So, if I run:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -filter_complex "[0:1]pan=2c|c0=c0|c1=c1[stereo]" -map "[stereo]" "a.audio.mov"
```

It works fine - I get the audio file with the correct channels.

But when I run:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -filter_complex "[0:1]pan=2c|c0=c0|c1=c1[stereo]" -map "[stereo]" -ss 00:00:01 "a.audio.mov"
```

I get the following error

> [trim for output stream 0:0 @ 0000000002145720] Cannot select channel
>   layout for the link between filters trim for output stream 0:0 and
>   output stream 0:0.
>   [trim for output stream 0:0 @ 0000000002145720] 
>   Unknown channel layouts not supported, try specifying a channel layout
>   using 'aformat=channel_layouts=something'.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Your 2nd command works for me on a movie with a 6-channel AC3 track.  BTW, you probably want to use `-c:a libfdk_aac`, not the default AAC encoder.  Is your ffmpeg version old?  Does `-ss` work on that input stream when you aren't using that filter?

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes! I had an older version of FFmpeg - it works in the latest version!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was bug in atrim filter, not supporting unknown channel layouts, it should be fixed in latest ffmpeg.